# Using Sun Netra 240 to Host asp.net Web page

Tags: iis, web-server, asp.net, windows, sun

My boss was offered a Sun Netra 240 server, still in the box.  The machine,purchased in 2008, is has two single core 1.5GHZ processors and two gigabytes of RAM.

My boss asked if it would be worth installing Windows Server and running our site from it.  I don't know if Windows would have the correct drivers for the box, nor if it has enough power to run our site without performance problems.

Our site is an Umbraco CMS(ASP.NET 2.0) site with many custom ASP.NET programs accessing an external SQL server.  We typically do not exceed 40 to 50 concurrent users.

Is this system a viable option for our webpage?

Comment: If you've always opened the box, can you verify the processors are x86 and not ultrasparc?

Comment: We do not have physical access to the server yet, I think (am not sure) that it appears to be a ultrasparc processor.

Comment: If the processors are sparc, I don't think any version of windows will run on it. Only Solaris and some custom Linux/BSD builds (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC)